# What animal is making odd footprints and squeaking sounds under my guest house?

Tags: animal-identification, animal-tracks

With the recent snow, I ran across some odd tracks that go under my guest house. I got closer to the area where the tracks ended and was surprised to hear odd squeaking noises from whatever made the tracks.

Does anyone know what the tracks belong to?

*Click on the pictures to see close-up view.*
[image: a pic with front and back] [image: another front and back] 
[image: and another]

Comment: Thank you very much, Sue. I live in Madison Alabama, I do have woods around me. I normally only find tracks I'm familiar with like deer, coyote, rabbits and so on. I'm very uncertain on these though. The tracks alternate between, they are in a pretty small area as though it takes only a certain path to and from under the house. It was only about an inch of snow and the tracks were not in the dirt itself.

Comment: A better idea of size and stride distance would be useful, but possibilities include raccoon, possum, and porcupine.

Comment: Okay idk how clear it is but the two middle toes are close together and the toe on the left and right of it look shorter and are spread more

Comment: Could be a skunk imho... Not sure though http://www.wildernesscollege.com/images/450xNxskunk-lope.jpg.pagespeed.ic.qLqAKWHi6M.jpg

Comment: Take a look at https://www.google.com/search?q=animal+tracks&biw=1366&bih=645&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjjmtvA6MXKAhXEjz4KHXP8C1cQsAQIGw&dpr=1  and also http://www.bear-tracker.com/guide.html  and  http://www.bear-tracker.com/

Answer (score 4):

Those look like fox tracks.  We do have foxes in the Southeastern US.  They are characterized by having the two middle toes noticeably (almost a full toe) forward of the outer two toes.

I've ruled out squirrel, opossum, rabbit, mouse, rat, raccoon, cat, and weasel in the process of my research.

For an example, look near the bottom of this page:  http://www.drgreenway.org/DiscoveryTrailAnimals.html